# Accessing has_many objects from model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models caled `Payroll`,`Allowance`,`Deduction`.Here Payroll has the relation has_many `allowances` and has_many `deductions`.

`Payroll` model has the following schema

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: payrolls
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  empno      :string(255)
#  name       :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime        not null
#  updated_at :datetime        not null
#  totsal     :decimal(, )
```

and the model is as following

```
  class Payroll < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :empno, :name,:allowances_attributes,:deductions_attributes
  has_many :allowances, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :deductions, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :allowances,allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :deductions,allow_destroy: true
  validates :empno, presence: true, uniqueness:{ case_sensitive: false }
  validates_length_of :empno, :minimum => 5, :maximum => 5
  before_save :create_fullname
  before_save :saltotal
  def create_fullname
    emp = Employee.find_by_empno(self.empno)
    self.name= "#{emp.first_name} #{emp.last_name}"   
  end
```

and `deduction.rb`

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: deductions
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  empno      :string(255)
#  amount     :decimal(, )
#  dtype      :string(255)
#  dedtype    :string(255)
#  payroll_id :integer
#  created_at :datetime        not null
#  updated_at :datetime        not null
#
class Deduction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :payroll
  attr_accessible :amount, :dedtype, :empno, :dtype
end
```

and `allowance.rb`

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: allowances
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  empno      :string(255)
#  amount     :decimal(, )
#  atype      :string(255)
#  payroll_id :integer
#  created_at :datetime        not null
#  updated_at :datetime        not null
#
class Allowance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :payroll
  attr_accessible :amount, :empno, :atype
end
```

I take the value of all this from a single form handled by `payrolls` controller and it works perfectly.

Now I am trying to calculate the total salary using values from deduction and allowances and store it in `totsal` variable in `Payroll` model.

so I wrote a `before_save` function in model.But the issue I am facing is how to access the variables from nested attributes from the function in model.Following is what I wrote but it doesnt work:

```
def saltotal
    self.allowances do |allowance|
      self.totsal+=allowance.amount
    end
    self.deductions do |deduction|
      self.totsal-=deduction.amount
    end  
    self.totsal
  end
```

When I check the value from rails console I see the value of `totsal`is nil.
So how should i actually access it. I also tried adding `.each`(`self.allowances.each do`) but it returns an error saying no such method. How am I suppose to do this.

Comment: You can do this with a `each`. What is exacly the error "no suck method" ? What's the original Class ?

Comment: @ForgetTheNorm I get `undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: OK, that's just your `self.totsal` which is unitialized. Try to add `self.totsal ||= 0.0` at first line of your function `saltotal`.

Comment: @ForgetTheNorm Ahh should kick myself.Thnx man its working perfectly that was the issue.If you add an answer I will upvote and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused due to a stupid mistake of mine as pointed out by  ForgetTheNorm in the comments.

I hadn't initialized `self.totsal`. Adding `self.totsal ||= 0.0` at the beginning of  function `saltotal` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As your dependent object are not saving before parent save so you will not get value of `self.allowances` and `self.deductions`. So try use observer on `after_save` will resolve your issue. You have to update object in observer. Hope this help.

Comment: Correct: you can not `save` the object when `allowances` or `deductions` are not saved. **But** he didn't save object, he just assign local variable, so this is not the issue. You can access values of allowances or deductions even if they are not saved.